# How do I find a recently added contact?

Tags: ios, contacts

I recently met someone and got them to type their info into my contacts.  I was really busy for a few days and didn't get around to contacting them.  Now I can't remember their name.  Is there a way to view the most recent additions to my contacts list?

Comment: I've discovered that there's a IFTTT recipe that adds a note in my calendar whenever I add a new contact.  In the future that will take care of the issue.

Answer (score 9):

On iPhone, you can download several different apps.

The one I found was free, quick, and simple called '[Recent Contacts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/recent-contacts/id541831736?mt=8)' by Kyle Gorlick.

On Android there are also several apps, but I have not tried them myself.

Comment: Recent Contacts does have In-App-Purchases, or at least one for $2 called "Mystery Features".  Don't know what that's about.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in contacts app doesn't provide a user-friendly way to search by 'most recent'.  This app is very basic and is good for most users but, as you've experienced, if you need something a bit more advanced, it won't work as well.  You can try doing a Spotlight search by the location you were at or by the company that person works for, any little thing they might've added to their contact on your iPhone.

If none of those approaches work, and you're not willing to jailbreak to get access to the Contacts database, you can try going thru each name one-by-one until you see it.  It's slow and annoying, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered a free app called iContacts+ (there are several such apps, I just grabbed the first that didn't look too ghastly).  It allowed me to search by most recent addition.

Comment: That's good to hear!  Please mark my answer as correct so others with the same issue can find an answer.

Comment: Can no longer find this one, and the only iContacts app I found needed me to create an account on their website and sync my contact info to them, which I did not like the sound of. I tried a different app which I added in an answer below: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276294/194618

Comment: It appears to be so.  iContacts+ is no longer available.  I have withdrawn my answer.

Comment: Rather than attempting to keep up to date I'll leave it up to the community to select the best answer with their votes.  Therefore I will abstain from selecting an answer to the question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-timeline/id988504062?mt=8) to see recently added contacts. It's not free, but apart from those others, it has a widget.

Answer (score 0):

[Recents](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/recents/id1010975884?mt=8) is another that's available on the iPhone that I find attractive.  It's also well reviewed with 4.5/5 stars from 14 reviewers.  I haven't personally had cause to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I add my contacts to a Group I created called "recent contacts" and then remove them after I synch to salesforce database or tag them with the info needed to recall them. Its a non-app workaround but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Links is a newer app that syncs with the Contacts app. You add new contacts through it and it creates a timeline of when they were added. It also stores where you were, which is a cool feature. The full name is [Links the Contacts Companion](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/links-the-contacts-companion/id1254271336?mt=8).

Answer (score -2):

There’s a new free iOS app (I just created) called Recent Contacts - Reco by Tav Shande.

Link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/recent-contacts-reco/id1447780700?mt=8

I’m currently working on an android version too. It also has a feature called auto photo finder which will automatically find profile photos of your contacts via Google contacts api.

[image: Reco][image: Recent contacts app]

Comment: Kindly mention your affiliation with the app in your answer.

Answer (score -3):

Contacts by creation app from appstore is all you need.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review